# Adding strings to an arraylist in order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm writing a class called HighSchool that has an arraylist of strings called universities in it. It is my goal to create a method called addCollege(String c) which takes the string, checks the list, then as long as the string already isn't in the list it places it in its correct alphabetical order. This what I've made so far but it only sorts the first part of the list. I'm also trying to do this without collections.sort.

```
    public void addCollege(String c){
    String s="";
    for(int i=0; i<=universities.size()-1; i++){
        if(c.equals(universities.get(i)))
            return;
    }
    universities.add(c);
    for(int p=1; p<=universities.size()-1; p++)
        if(universities.get(p-1).compareTo(universities.get(p))>0){
                s=universities.get(p);
                universities.set(p, universities.get(p-1));
                universities.set(p-1, s);

        }
    }
```

This is the content of the tester. Most of it isn't relevant to my problem:

```
  public class schoolTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    School s=new School(1000, "600 Pine Lane", "Pines School", "Bob Smith");
    int[] x={4,4,4,4,4,4};
    Elementary e=new Elementary(2000, "601 Pine Lane", "Everglades", "Bobby Smith", x);
    ArrayList<String>uni=new ArrayList<String>();
    uni.add("Harvard");
    uni.add("MIT");
    uni.add("Georgia Tech");
    uni.add("UCF");
    HighSchool h=new HighSchool(4000, "602 Pine Lane", "hi-school", "bob smith", uni);
    h.addCollege("Berkely");
    h.addCollege("Miami");
    h.addCollege("FSU");
    h.addCollege("FGCU");
    System.out.println(h.getColleges());
    h.addCollege("FSU");
    System.out.println(h.getColleges());

}
```

}

Comment: I'm assuming that this is for school, ruling out List.Contains() as well?

One thing i would do to start - when comparing the names, add a toUpper() on both - or equalsIgnoreCase() just in case they come in with varying cases

Comment: Good idea. Ive noticed java could get confused when dealing with different cases.

Comment: And the reason its not working, is that you're attempting to sort using only one sweep through the array

Assuming you dont want to do it recursively, add a while
flag = 1;
while(flag == 1){
     Your sorting loop here
     if change was made set flag to 1, otherwise 0}

Comment: You're awesome my friend! Type that in as in answer so I can give you the credit you deserve

Answer (score 2):

You're better off with the [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

It has the built-in capability of preventing duplicates, and if you properly implement the `compareTo` method, have the items inside it sorted any way you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You should use TreeSet look below code

```
public class Test2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<String> uni = new TreeSet();
    // Add elements to the tree set
    uni.add("Harvard");
    uni.add("MIT");
    uni.add("Georgia Tech");
    uni.add("UCF");
    uni.add("600 Pine Lane");
    System.out.println(uni);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to convert all the strings to the same case, and run a few more iterations of my sort. Credit to Jordan Fryar:

```
  public void addCollege(String c){
    String s="";
    for(int i=0; i<=universities.size()-1; i++){
        if(c.equals(universities.get(i)))
            return;
    }
    universities.add(c);
    for(int t=0; t<universities.size(); t++){
    for(int p=1; p<=universities.size()-1; p++)
        if(universities.get(p-1).compareTo(universities.get(p))>0){
                s=universities.get(p);
                universities.set(p, universities.get(p-1));
                universities.set(p-1, s);

        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like it is for school I will point you in the right direction, for all coding problems, by saying:

1. **Break down your algorithm into parts** (I.e Methods)
2. **Name EVERYTHING descriptively**

Just this will give you a hell of a head start. The only thing that you can get away with giving a single-letter variable name is your loop variable, though this (by convention) is generally an i, j or k.

It will be a lot easier to see what is going on if you do. Here is what I ended up with after cleaning up your code a little (trying not to change the algorithm). I also have not included the `universityAlreadyAdded(String)` method since it isn't important at the moment.

```
List<String> universities = new ArrayList<>();

public void addUniversity(String university) {
    if(universityAlreadyAdded(university)) {
        return;
    }

    universities.add(university);

    siftLastUniversityIntoSortedPosition();
}

public void siftLastUniversityIntoSortedPosition() {
    for(int p = 1; p <= universities.size() - 1; p++) {
        String currentUni = universities.get(p - 1);
        String nextUni = universities.get(p);
        if(currentUni.compareTo(nextUni) > 0) {
                swapElementsAtIndices(p - 1, p);
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at the `siftLastUniversityIntoSortedPosition()` method (At least that is what it appeared to me you were trying to do), you can see that the problem is that you want to sift the last added element into sorted position but your `for` loop is going up.

Without actually trying it myself, perhaps you could try making your algorithm start from `universities.size() - 1` and counting down. This would mean you could actually shift your last element down (since this is the only element that isn't sorted yet).
Thus your loop would start:

```
for(int p = universities.size() - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
```

I shall leave the rest for you to experiment with and finish off!